# Tyk Dashboard Set Dashboard URL

Tags: api, docker, devops, gateway, tyk

Hi everyone i have got a tyk api gateway and pro dashboard for managing api's. These are living at different machines .

When I check the scripts at tyk gateway i've seen comment sign at the line which changing the DASHBOARD_URL shown as below . How I can change the dashboard url of my tyk gateway application .

My starting script is shown as below .

```
  sudo /opt/tyk-gateway/install/setup.sh --dashboard=1 --listenport=8080 --redishost=<hostname> --redisport=6379
```

Dashboard at the public Ip : aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd:3000

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your dashboard URL to `use_db_app_options.connection_string` and `policies.policy_connection_string` in `tyk.conf` after running your `setup.sh` script.